# Не видит библиотеку numpy

Tags: python

Пытаюсь импортировать библиотеку `numpy`. При запуске кода в консоли PyCharm пишет

> `No module named 'numpy'`.

Хотя он был установлен через pip.

Comment: Может, у Вас виртуальное окружение? А в нём нет модуля `numpy`?

Comment: numpy может и установлен, вот только в библиотеках проекта его нет, пичарм выдает подсказки, где предлагает установить модуль, это и делайте

Comment: Тогда возникает другая проблема.Когда нажимаю установить numpy,то в начале он пытается это сделать, а потом выдает, что не установлен из-за отсутствия c++ 14.Но опять же он есть на компьютере.

Comment: Перейдите во вкладку terminal внутри PyCharm (снизу) и проверьте наличие numpy пакета с помощью команды ```pip list```. PyCharm terminal автоматически входит в рабочее окружение для проекта.

Comment: Добавьте версию ОС, версию PyCharm, версию python, как именно вы устанавливаете `numpy` и какое используете окружение для PyCharm - Anaconda, Virtualenv или иное.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы установить библиотеку в `PyCharm` необходимо:

- в PyCharm перейти во вкладку **File -> Settings -> Project: YOUR_PROJECT_NAME -> Project Interpreter**.
- Нажать на `+` и добавьте numpy к списку библиотек.
- Дождаться, когда numpy установится

Также проверьте, что вы выбираете верный интерпретатор. Путь к нему и версия python будут написаны в той же вкладке в окне `Project Interpreter`.

Также вы можете создать файл `requirements.txt` с содержимым

```
numpy
```

PyCharm предложит вам установить плагин для работы с ним(если он еще не установлен).

Затем, после перезагрузки, PyCharm предложит установить библиотеки, перечисленные в файле `requirements.txt`, в текущий выбранный интерпретатор. В всплывающем окне выберете `Install requirement` и дождитесь загрузки.